# Microphone software boost is extremely low and boosts also noise

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I am using a distribution based on Ubuntu. I have a problem that I have been facing on basically any Linux distro I have tried. I have a condenser microphone (NW-700) that under Windows sounds perfectly.

Under Linux tho it's completely different. Normally on Windows I use boost function (that btw appears only if I have correct motherboard drivers installed) to boost microphone volume. Under Linux there is not any boost like this (as far as I know) and boosting it normally with PulseAudio volume control means extreme static noise (I can't even hear myself over that noise).

[image: screenshot]

My theory is that the motherboard (Asus Prime B250 Pro) has actually some hardware based booster that is controlled by this driver (which is not working under Linux).

Is there any way to solve it? I am connecting the microphone directly to motherboard.

Thanks.

EDIT: Found out that there is a boost option in `alsamixer`, but it seems like it also boosts the noise.

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: Please be more specific. Which distribution do you use (name,version)? Which soundcard is in use? What do you mean with `connecting the microphone directly to motherboard`? Do you use 48V phantom-power for the mic? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1175092/edit) your question to add additionlal info.

Comment: @mook765 I mean what do you want to add? Yes. I am directly connecting the microphone to onboard sound-card. I don't use phantom power (altho I have it but it does not really make a big difference - there is still lot of static noise compared to windows).

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured that out. Even tho the mic volume and gain were correctly set, I had to set general capture gain in alsamixer settings.

This is final microphone result:
https://youtu.be/Jm7VShCJZZ4